# Customs trade data of Brazil and China needed

Tags: data-request, data-format, database, china, brazil

I'm looking for customs trade data of Brazil and China.
For Brazil I need export of poultry meat (HS-code 0207)
For China I need import to country.
And all these data must contain such information as: name of company-exporter and consignee, quantities, value, price in USD, Incoterms, detailed description of the goods and country of origin.
I have already wrote to lots of companies providing customs data, but there was no one who can provide all the information requred.
Maybe anyone knows where to find these information and can advice me company, which supply data I described.